# 4 mosfets inverter circuit low output voltage problem

Tags: power-electronics, inverter, switching, h-bridge, voltage

I have used the mosfets as a switch to generate a simple square wave at the output. Taking the concept from the simple switches if there were switches instead of the mosfets as shown below then we must have a voltage of amplitude equal to +Vin and -Vin across the resistor. Moving this forward when I used mosfets then instead of getting +Vin/-Vin I am getting a lower voltage at the output shown below. I dont know why isnt the mosfet switching properly. Kindly help me solve the problem.
[image]

The switching concept taken from the [site](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIqhAX0I7lI) is shown above.
[image]

[image]

With an input of 20V I am getting +1.26/-1.26 instead of +20/-20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the "explanations" of the function of bipolar junction transistors and mosfets imply that they are "switches". They are not really switches unless you use them in a circuit that makes them act like switches.

It's a fair assumption that power mosfets with VDS ratings above say 25-50V require 10V gate-source voltage to fully turn on.

You are using all N-MOS devices. To turn them on, assume that the gate has to be 10V higher than the source. You'll need a voltage multiplier to get those higher voltages needed on the high-side switches. Such circuits are sometimes called bootstrap gate voltage or boost gate voltage generators. The switching action of the mosfet "walks" the boost capacitor up to a voltage higher than the supply voltage.

A high-side booststrapped gate driver might looks something like the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKcw5H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

M7 is an inverter and generates the gate waveform for M5-M6 inverter. Let's assume that the total parasitic capacitance from A to GND is about 60pF - that includes gate capacitances of M5 and M6. Point A's response has a time constant of 10kΩx 60pF=0.6μs. The gain of M5/M6 speeds up the effective transition time seen between R3 and R4. The time constant at B is about 60ns. Gain of M3/M4 again speeds things up, and the gate of S1 sees a time constant of 100Ωx1nF=0.1μs. That's a reasonable slew rate for your application I think.

R1,R2 and R3,R4 not only control the dV/dt on the subsequent gate, but also limit the shoot-through current when M3 and M4 or M6 and M5 are both conducting during the state transition between logic 1 and logic 0 (and vice versa).

The bootstrap works as follows:

- When OUT is at 0V, C1 charges to about 30V via D1.
- As soon as OUT starts slewing high, the capacitor C1 "rides along" on top of that voltage, diode D1 turns off, and the BOOST voltage is OUT+20V (approximately). In practice, C1 will discharge somewhat, but as long as the BOOST voltage is 10V above OUT, M1's gate-source voltage will be high enough to let M1 act as a switch, as desired.

M3..M7 are "small signal" devices, but they need to withstand up to 2xsupply voltage, or 40V in the circuit shown.

You need such a high-side driver for both S1 and S2 in the first diagram in the question.

You can also use a dedicated high-side driver IC, of course. The driver IC will implement a circuit that fulfills the same function, just implemented using sub-circuits that make sense on a silicon die. The circuit I've drawn is how it might be done using discrete mosfets on a PCB/breadboard.

Comment: The voltage (Vdd) applied to the anode of the boost diode should not be the bridge voltage (S1 drain), in general. Vcc should come from a low voltage supply different from the bridge voltage. In the circuit diagram, the voltage on the drain of S1 cannot be graeter than VGSmax.

Comment: In _When OUT is at 0V, C1 charges to about 30V via D1_ don't understand how C1 can charge to about 30V when the supply voltage on the anode of D1 is 20V. Should it be _When OUT is at 0V, C1 charges to about 20V via D1_?

Comment: @ChesterGillon It’s a typo :)

Comment: @RussellH Good catch. I’ll fix the answer to take care of that.

Answer (score 3):

You're not driving the gates of the MOSFETs to a high enough voltage.  Your logic level is 5 or 3.3V but if you want 20V across the resistor, then the top MOSFETs need a gate voltage of close to 30V relative to ground (Vgs of +10V) and while you're at it, the bottom MOSFETs should have a stronger gate drive too since the IRF1404s aren't logic level.  You usually get this by using a gate driver with a charge pump since many circuits don't have a rail above the supply voltage.

Edit: a gate driver that can control all four transistors at the same time will also keep you from having to manage four independent signals while preventing you from doing things like turning on top and bottom transistors on the same side simultaneously.  They also generally have more current handling capability than a standard logic level output which is handy for charging and discharging the gate capacitance.

Comment: Suppose I have to use a voltage of 200/300 even then Do I have to use a 10-15V at the top MOSFET? I guess this should make that On.

Comment: Vgs of 200V would destroy the MOSFET. The IRF1404 has a max Vgs of 20V, which is as high as most MOSFETs go.  Drain-source breakdown voltage is minimum 40V but I wouldn't feel comfortable going much above 30V with that device really.  For 200-300V, I would look into IGBTs.

Comment: Considering I am using a MOSFET of higher voltage or an IGBT then does that rule apply for it also? Because one cannot provide a 180V to the gate to get a 200V switching.

Comment: @kam1212 One *can* provide 180V (actually, you need 210V to turn on the high-side MOSFET at 200V supply voltage) when you build a circuit physically that deals with a 200V working voltage. Does your conception that "one cannot provide 180V" apply to the circuit simulator you are using, or do you mean that you don't have any idea how to build a physical circuit that generates a 210V control voltage using a ground-referenced logic-level input?

Comment: An IGBT have a max gate voltage of 20V. How can I use 180V for that?

Comment: @kam1212 the gate voltage may be 20V higher or lower than source (for a MOSFET) or emitter (for an IGBT). If the source pin is at 200V (which it will be while the MOSFET is on), the allowed gate voltage is between 180V and 220V. To have the MOSFET really turned on, it should be between 210V and 220V.

Answer (score 3):

The upper MOSFETs are connected as source followers (aka [common drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain)). A source follower cannot produce a voltage at the source any higher than what is applied at the gate and, in reality, the source voltage will be several volts lower than the gate voltage.

That is why we use proper high-side MOSFET drivers; they ensure that  a decent activation voltage between gate and source is applied (circa 10 to 15 volts in most cases).